# how to change CSS priority (don't use !important)

Tags: css

If the css is as below:

```
input[type="text"]
{
     border: 1px solid green; 
}

.text
{
     border: 1px solid red ; 
}
```

And if the html is as below:

```
<div>
 <input type="text" class="text"/>
</div>​
```

The `border-color` of the textbox is green.
It seems that the "element" has the higher priority.
How to make the .class valid? Is it a must to use the `!important`?

Any other choices?

---

I tested below CSS code:

```
input[type="text"]
{
     border: 1px solid green; 
}

input[type="text"] .text
{
     border: 1px solid red; 
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div>
     <input type="text" class="text"/>
</div>
```

Guess what?​

Still Green.

Remove the space in 'input[type="text"] .text'
it becomes input[type="text"].text .
That's ok. The border color is red.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `C` in CSS stands for cascading. You just need to give it higher precedence then the other rule.

```
input.text
{
     border: 1px solid red ; 
}
```

Comment: div .text or input.text instead of div.text
​

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Set default border for `text` elements */
.text
{
     border: 1px solid red; 
}

/* Override for input elements */
input.text
{
     border: 1px solid green; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Styles are applied in sequence, but also must follow *specificity* rules.  The `.text` is less specific than `input[type="text"]`, so the green border "wins."  If you make the red border rule more specific, you can get the results you seem to be expecting.

Try something like `input.text` and see what happens. If that doesn't do it, you'll have to get even more specific.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of weight of your selectors.

With

```
input[type="text"]
```

You are passing both `input` and `[type=text]` as selector, so you're passing a total of two.

With

```
.text
```

You are passing only one. This translates in less weight and less specificity, so the first selector wins over the second.

By adding `input` before (i.e. input.text) you're adding more weight to second style, which will prevail as you'd expect from Cascading Style Sheets.

Specificity is easily visualized through websites like [Specificity Calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/).