# Styling a library component once it's been packaged?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass

How do we style library packaged component from via `styles.scss`?

For example suppose we have a `<hello-component>` and the template looks like this:

```
<div><h1 class="fs-HelloHeading">Hello!</h1><div>
```

How can be override the CSS inside `fs-HelloHeading` class and do it in a way that is context sensitive?

So for example if `<hello-component>` is inside `<party-component>` then it should have a yellow background, but if it's inside `funeral-component` then it should have a black background, and we would set these by overriding the styles in `fs-HelloComponent`.  Thoughts?

My end goal is to override classes that are packaged with a component.  For example I have these packaged with an Angular Material Table Component.

```
.mat-header-cell {
  justify-content: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 12rem;
}

.mat-cell {
  justify-content: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 12rem;
}
```

However I may want to change the width from outside the component later in a specific context, so I was thinking about doing that by adding additional css classes to the `mat-row-element`.

Comment: Answerers are advising to use `!important`, but !important should be a _last resort_ or used for _very_ specific situations, not used in the normal everyday course of things.  [Avoid Using !important](https://uxengineer.com/css-specificity-avoid-important-css/) [how to change CSS priority (don't use !important)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13964052/17300) [When Using !important is The Right Choice](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) [CSS is !important](https://medium.com/markuptips/css-is-important-960a9921e454) https://lmgtfy.app/?q=don%27t+use+!important

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to override a style with the `!important` keyword. from top to bottom, the last `!important` will be applied. To set individual stylings depending on the surrounding element you can just 'mimic' the DOM-structure. Here is an example what you can put just on the end of the SCSS-file.

```
party-component {
    hello-component {
        background-color: yellow !important;
    }
}

funeral-component {
    hello-component {
        background-color: black !important;
    }
}
```

*Please note that you have to replace colors and component-names with actual values.*

Comment: I changed the question a little bit so that the CSS class is nested deeper in the template.  I'm actually wonder how to go about overriding classes for Angular Material Data Table from outside the table.  So I'm trying to figure out how to override CSS classes that are already part of the packaged component.  Thought?

Comment: @Ole Like i said, you just need to make sure your Override-CSS ist the last one loaded. Maybe you add your own SCSS-file and include it at last. You also need to 'compile' your SCSS-file to a CSS-file.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to define another custom selector with more or equal specificity to your CSS selectors.

if any rule is overridden,then you need to  use !important flag to force your custom css rules, also consider that when you are using bootstrap, then some utilities classes have !important attribute.

```
<h1 id="custom-id" class="fs-HelloHeading">Hello {{ name }}!</h1>

style.css:

#custom-id {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I can't change the template because the component is pre packaged ...

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use :host and ::ng-deep like

```
:host ::ng-deep  .fs-HelloHeading { // in party-component css file
    background-color: yellow;
}

:host ::ng-deep  .fs-HelloHeading { // in funeral-component css file
    background-color: black ;
}
```

it will look for all the child elements of these components
for more detail. Here's the docs: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/

Comment: Well ... It's just that `::ng-deep` is deprecated ...

Comment: oh I see...so another approach is to write a directive to custom behavior of this component or you know just add a class to lib component for  your specific context ` <hello-component class="funeral"></hello-component>` and add custom style with that